# Send two list side by side through email?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a little problem here. I got an application which sends a list of files name through email notifying the user that those files has exceeded a certain size limit. But now I want it to not only send the files name but also the files size. I manage to attach the file size to the email. But my problem is the way it displayed. I want it to displayed like :

```
THE FILES :

filename1 = filesize1
filename2 = filesize2
filename3 = filesize3
..
..
..

HAS REACHED ITS LIMITS!
```

But my current display format in the email is like :

```
THE FILES :

filename1
filename2
filename3
filesize1
filesize2
filesize3

HAS REACHED ITS LIMITS!
```

And now I don't know how to change the display format like the first one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is my code snippet :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        count = 0;
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer.Start();
        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> files = new List<string>();
        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> files1 = new List<string>();
        //List<string> s1 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\test", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>();
        List<string> s1 = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\gdimaging\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>();
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\hios\DATA", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\imgviewer\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\newcnas\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\newpod\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\OMS\data", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());
        s1.AddRange(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"F:\WEBIMG", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList<string>());

        dt.Columns.Add("File_Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("File_Type");
        dt.Columns.Add("File_Size");
        dt.Columns.Add("Create_Date");

        foreach (string s in s1) 
        {   
            try
            {   
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(s);
                FileSystemInfo sysInfo = new FileInfo(s);
                dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["File_Name"] = sysInfo.Name;
                dr["File_Type"] = sysInfo.Extension;
                dr["File_Size"] = (info.Length / 1024).ToString();
                dr["Create_Date"] = sysInfo.CreationTime.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);


                if ((info.Length / 1024) > 1500000)
                {
                    MyFiles = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    //files.Add(sysInfo.Name.ToString());
                    //files1.Add(info.Length.ToString());
                    //arr = string.Join("<br/>", files.ToArray());
                    //arr1 = string.Join("<br/>", files1.ToArray());
                    MyFiles.Add(sysInfo.Name.ToString(), info.Length.ToString());
                }

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error : " + ex.Message);
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (arr != null)
        {
            ///Basic Email message
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            // Email to send to
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("shahrul1509@yahoo.com"));
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("shahrul_kakashi90@hotmail.com"));
            //set subject
            mailMessage.Subject = "FILE SIZE WARNING MESSAGE";
            //set body
            //mailMessage.Body = "THE FILES : <br/><br/>" + arr + arr1 + "<br/><br/> HAS REACH ITS SIZE LIMIT!!";
            mailMessage.Body = "THE FILES : <br/><br/>";
            foreach (string key in MyFiles.Keys)
            {
                mailMessage.Body += key + " = " + MyFiles[key] + "<br/>";
                mailMessage.Body += "<br/> HAS REACHED ITS SIZE LIMIT!";
            }
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("************", "Shahrul Nizam");
            //Identify the credentials to login to the gmail account
            string sendEmailsFrom = "**********";
            string sendEmailsFromPassword = "**********";
            NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(sendEmailsFrom, sendEmailsFromPassword);
            SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            mailClient.EnableSsl = true;
            mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            //mailClient.Timeout = 20000;
            mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            mailClient.Credentials = cred;
            mailClient.Send(mailMessage);
            //MessageBox.Show("Email Notification Sent!");
            //MessageBox.Show(fileList.ToString() + "overlimit!!");
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            count++;
            if (count == 600)
            {
                count = 0;
                timer.Stop();
                Application.Restart();
            }
    }
```

Comment: How are you currently generating the list of files too large?

Comment: There you go. I can't think of a more complete answer tonight, too late. Do note that if it helps, it's a good idea to give accepted answer -> it improves your rate and more people (much probably better then me) will be inclined to answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
/*step 1*/if ((info.Length / 1024) > 1500000)
                {//my size checking and storing it in an array
                    files.Add(sysInfo.Name.ToString());
                    files1.Add(info.Length.ToString());
                    arr = string.Join("<br/>", files.ToArray());
                    arr1 = string.Join("<br/>", files1.ToArray());
                }
/*step 2*/mailMessage.Body = "THE FILES : <br/><br/>" + arr + arr1 + "<br/><br/> HAS REACH ITS SIZE LIMIT!!";
```

to

```
/*step 1*/if ((info.Length / 1024) > 1500000)
                {//my size checking and storing it in an array
                    files.Add(sysInfo.Name.ToString());
                    files1.Add(info.Length.ToString());
                }
/*step2*/mailMessage.Body = "THE FILES : <br/><br/>";
for(int i=0; i<files.Count; i++)
  mailMessage.Body += files[i] + " = " + files1[i] + "<br/>;
mailMessage.Body += "<br/> HAS REACHED ITS SIZE LIMIT!!";
```

The extra `<br/>` at the last instance of the lists won't matter because the last lines start with 2 breaks (I removed one).

The suppositions I make:

- The lists are of the same size
- Each index in one, corresponds to the item in the other.

This could be done better with a DICTIONARY (of type ) like so:

```
/*step 1*/if ((info.Length / 1024) > 1500000)
                {//my size checking and storing it in an array
                    /* I suppose there is a Dictionary<string, string> MyFiles;
                    MyFiles = new Dictionary<string,string>(); instantiated like so*/
                    MyFiles.add(sysInfo.Name.ToString(), info.Length.ToString());
                }
                //attaching the array to the email body
                    /*step 2*/mailMessage.Body = "THE FILES : <br/><br/>";
                    foreach(string key in MyFiles.Keys)
                      mailMessage.Body += key + " = " + MyFiles[key] + "<br/>";
                    mailMessage.Body += "<br/> HAVE REACHED THEIR SIZE LIMIT!!";
```

Note that by better I do *NOT* mean more memory efficient. By better I mean less error-prone. Technically you have a key-value pairing. That is a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shingetsu! I've thought of using a for loop but I just don't know where to put the loop. I'm still new to programming so still need a lot to learn:). I've tried both of your solution but only the first one works. The second(dictionary) solution doesn't work for me. I don't know if I did any mistakes or what. The dictionary doesn't return any value.

Comment: For the dictionary, replace all occurances of files with the dictionary. oh well. if you want to learn programming for future I recommend you try C (for pointer understanding) and Common Lisp (good for you)

Comment: C and common lisp??understood. I'll look into it. I still got plenty to learn as I am still a newbie. Thanks again @Shingetsu!:)